# Can I join the Vigilants of Stendarr?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During my travels, I've met a few Vigilants of Stendarr. I discovered that they find and kill all kinds of a fun stuff (vampires, werewolves, etc). Recently, I even found their meeting place. Their line of work sounds pretty intriguing and I'm curious - can I become a Vigilant of Stendarr? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in Skyrim! Don't rule out the possibility for a mod or DLC, though!

Comment: Here's to hoping :/ It'd be such a neat faction to join

Comment: Daedra hunting as a DLC? mmmmh... nice :>

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it's possible. You need to kill 30 daedra and a vigilant will approach you and welcome you to the order.

Comment: None of the wikis mention this being possible, and I've killed far more than 30 daedra without it occurring. Could you please provide some form of verification?

Comment: I just kept going to mehrunes dagon's shrine after you get his dagger and one finally came to me